# Laravel illuminate html taking too much time

Tags: laravel

So I've decided to start using Laravel and found it awesome. I am using composer also. For now this is what I do in my terminal emulator in installing Illuminate/Html:

```
composer require illuminate/html
```

It is taking so long, is that normal? Or is there a way that when I create a new laravel app, I'll just copy paste anything to include illuminate/html?

Answer (score 1):

How long is it taking exactly? What happens when you run the command? What are the results?

Typically I just edit the `composer.json` file inside the root project directory and enter my dependencies manually, such as:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",

        "illuminate/html": "dev-master"
     }
}
```

Then open a command window inside the root project directory, and run `composer update`.

Comment: Composer update takes too much time also.. but will give it a try sir!